# Include Functions from File Relative Path (Python 3.10)

Tags: python, include

I'm attempting to include & call Python functions from a different `py` file, by providing a relative file path to the `os.path.join` function call.

Let's say I have two `py` files, `TEST1.py` and `TEST2.py`, and a function defined inside of `TEST2.py` called `TEST3()`.

Alongside the following directory structure:

```
TEST1.py
|____________TEST2.py
```

So `TEST1.py` is located one directory above `TEST2.py`.

With the following code inside of `TEST1.py`:

```
import os

CurrDirPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
CurrFileName = os.path.join(CurrDirPath, "../TEST2.py")

import TEST2

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    print(TEST2.TEST3())
```

And the following code inside of `TEST2.py`:

```
def TEST3():
    return "test"
```

Results in the following exception upon attempting to run `TEST1.py`:

```
   import TEST2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TEST2'
```

What is the proper way to include Python functions from a relative file path?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Is `TEST1.py` the main script with which you start the program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your files arranged like this:

```
│   test1.py
│
└──── sub_folder
      │   test2.py
```

Below Code should work:

```
import os
import sys

CurrDirPath = os.getcwd()
DesiredDirPath = CurrDirPath + os.sep + "sub_folder"    

sys.path.insert(1, DesiredDirPath)

import TEST2

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    print(TEST2.TEST3())
```

But, if your files arranged like this:

```
│   test2.py
│
└──── sub_folder
      │   test1.py
```

Below Code should work:

```
import os
import sys

CurrDirPath = os.getcwd()
# Below command, goes one folder back
DesiredDirPath = os.path.normpath(CurrDirPath + os.sep + os.pardir)    

sys.path.insert(1, DesiredDirPath)

import TEST2

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    print(TEST2.TEST3())
```

first you need to get Desired working directory and Then you need to add this path to known paths of the system, clearly at runtime, by this code:
`sys.path.insert(1, DesiredDirPath)`

Now you can import TEST2

There is nice discussion at below link:
[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html%5C)

If `test2.py` in located in subfolder, for example:

```
│   test1.py
│
└──── sub_folder
      │   test2.py
```

So for `test1.py`:

```
import os
import importlib.util
import sys


CurrDirPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
CurrFileName = os.path.join(CurrDirPath, r"sub_folder\test2.py")

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("test2", CurrFileName)
test2 = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules["module.name"] = test2
spec.loader.exec_module(test2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(test2.test3())
```

In `test2.py`:

```py
def test3():
    return 'test2'
```

More details in answer [How can I import a module dynamically given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-can-i-import-a-module-dynamically-given-the-full-path)